# How do I get rid of form flicker when FormStyle is bsNone in Delphi?

Tags: forms, delphi, vcl, flicker

Even `"DoubleBuffered"` property is `True`, when I restore minimized form, my form flickers.

But this issue occurs only if `"BorderStyle"` property is `bsNone`.

Any type of `"BorderStyle"` besides `"bsNone"` fixes my problem.

So, how can I prevent form flicker when I use `"bsNone"`?

PS: I minimize my form with my custom button which executes `Application.Minimize` command.

Comment: I made a quick test with a form (with `BorderStyle`= `bsNone` ) and some controls. A button runs `Application.Minimize` as you wrote. Restore from the taskbar. No flicker! Please edit your post and provide a [mre], and also provide the `.dfm` as text (you can use Alt-F12 to switch between form design and .dfm).

Comment: Btw, you do know, don't you, that you can search previous posts about your problem. E.g. enter in the search box '[delphi] form flicker' and you will get many previous posts about the same issue. (The [delphi] part limits the search to posts that are tagged 'delphi')

Comment: [Tom's suggestion as a link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+form+flicker) to learn from what the search box then contains. Since `flicker` is a tag on its own we can even combine both to [`[delphi] [flicker]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi+flicker).

Comment: @TomBrunberg My .dfm file is extremely long (approx. 4000 lines)

Comment: Ouch! But it is practically impossible to help you without knowing what your form looks like and what you do when you show it. Please reduce your form to only those (or some of the) components that flicker. The result of the reduced form may of course be that the flicker disappears. Search (as I told you in an other comment) for previous posts about how to reduce flicker. Be sure not to do any component construction or size or location adjustments of components in the 'OnShow' event.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my problem.

Here is what I do:

1. I have enabled `"TransparentColor"` property.
2. Then I have set `"TransparentColorValue"` value to `"clBackground"`.

Also I have removed the panel which I used it as the titlebar. Instead of that, I have inserted `TTitleBarPanel` to my form.

PS: I use C++ and Delphi as front-end languages; C++, JavaScript as back-end languages.